# Docker MySQL mysqli::real_connect():(HY000/2002): Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, docker, codeigniter, docker-compose

I'm new to docker/docker-compose. I'm trying to connect 2 containers which are the **CodeIgniter** application and **MySQL**. I can't seems to solve the **'mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused'** issue on my web app. I was able to ping from inside the container to the other and vice versa.

This is my **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
version: '3'

services:

  web:
    container_name: ciblog
    build: .
    links: 
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes: 
      - .:/var/www/html/

  db:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ciblog
    volumes:
      - ./assets/sql/ciblog.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ciblog.sql
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-install mysqli && \
    docker-php-ext-install mbstring && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/  &&  \
    docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN service apache2 restart
```

Here's my database.php configuration:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'dbport' => '3306',
    'hostname' => 'db',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'ciblog',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => FALSE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Could anyone please help me identify the issue? Thank you in advance.
Here's my GitHub repository in case you want to see the files: https://github.com/josephsim/docker-ciblog

Answer (score 5):

In Docker Compose-based setups, you can use the names of services as hostnames.  In your example, set

```
'hostname' => 'db'
```

[Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) discusses this in more detail.

Docker containers don't have consistent IP addresses, and it's usually not useful to manually look them up.  You don't need `links:` in modern Docker either and removing that line won't be harmful.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion sir, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solve it. Changing the MySQL version seem to work.

```
image: mysql:5.7
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50169745/12555817

Answer (score 0):

In Docker Compose-based setups, you can use the names of services as hostnames. In your example, set

'hostname' => 'db'

Answer (score -1):

if you are using docker with version 2.0.0 and below. please use `image: mysql:5.7`
I fixed my issue.

Comment: This is already covered by another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59463467/ Please don't post answers that don't add any additional information.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).